# MySQL how to multiply various column values and return the maximum product

Tags: mysql

I have a `MySQL` database and would like to know how to multiply specific column values with one another and then, of these product values, return the maximum.  **For example:**

Let's say the Database table is called `Power` and has the following column entries

`Power table` contains the following column-names with the entries:

`A | B | C | D | E | F`
`2 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 1`

Thus `A * B = 2 * 3 = 6` and `C * D = 30` and `E * F = 7`

Thus the maximum value to return is `30`.

Any ideas / directions are much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried anything? Any error? Any thing?

Comment: bub and Jay, thank you for enquiring.  JPG (below) answered my question and it works fine :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest):

```
select GREATEST(A*B, C*D, E*F) as maxVal
from Power
```

[<kbd>SqlFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4369cf/1)

Comment: Thank you !! I am new to MySQL and this is the first post (on all the forums) that helped me...so simple !  Thank you once again!